# Error domain on odoo field

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

**Problem:**

On my main model I've got a many2one field that points to my submodel.
I Wanted to filter the types available to select for the user with a calculated domain. However it gives me an error that the method doesn't exist. Does someone know how to fix this error?

**Code example:**

```
class my_class(models.Model):    
    _name = "my.model"
    name = fields.Char('Name', required=True)
    issue_type_id = fields.Many2one('my.model.type',"My Model Type", domain='_search_my_model_types', required=True)

    @api.model
    def _search_my_model_types(self):
        my_model_type_ids = []
        return [('id', 'in', my_model_type_ids)]

class my_class_type(models.Model):
    _name = "my.model.type"
    name = fields.Char("Name")
```

**The error:**

```
Uncaught Error: NameError: name '_search_my_model_types' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class my_class(models.Model):    
    _name = "my.model"

    #method definition before use
    @api.model
    def _search_my_model_types(self):
        my_model_type_ids = []
        return [('id', 'in', my_model_type_ids)]

    name = fields.Char('Name', required=True)
    #domain function not as a string
    issue_type_id = fields.Many2one('my.model.type',"My Model Type", domain=_search_my_model_types, required=True)
```